# Assign string with space to variable from command line argument

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have to get a string with space(sometimes without)assigned to a variable as input from the command line argument to the script and search the given string in a file.

My script is not considering the space passed to it, instead, it is taking the first word only

I execute as

```
./search_pattern.sh ticket_no="ticket3456" pattern="Error configuring"


for argument in "$@"; do

key="${argument%%=*}"

value="${argument#*=}"

case "${key}" in

pattern)    pattern="${value}";;
ticket_no)  ticket_no="$value";;
esac

done

echo "pattern is $pattern"

echo "ticket is $ticket_no"
```

I am getting the output as

```
  pattern is Error

  ticket is ticket3456
```

Comment: Try putting `#!/bin/bash` on the first line of the script, or using `bash ./search_pattern.sh ticket_no="ticket3456" pattern="Error configuring"`.  I suspect this is running under the default shell, not `bash`.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Do you call the script from within another script?

Comment: @cdarke , it is used inside. I have pasted only a part of script.

Comment: @hek2mgl We have to call directly only, as we pass variables in different method while implementing, so it need to be direct as i mentioned. I need changes in code instead changing in arguments passing

Comment: Like I said, the code works.

Comment: Still it is producing same result

Comment: What you show is correct. Something else is mishandling the space-containing argument. Are you sure you don't have a call like `./search_pattern.sh ticket_no="ticket3456" pattern=$pattern`? Try adding a default case (`*) echo "Unknown key: $key"` to your `case` statement.

Comment: Also try a debug print of the whole argument before you split it, incase it is already broken.

Comment: Run it with a full trace:  `bash -x ./search_pattern.sh ticket_no="ticket3456" pattern="Error configuring"`

Comment: Also, run it from the command-line rather than from another script, it could be that other script which is messing it up.

Comment: The issue facing was due to that i was passing arguments to function where it is considering space and not escaping it when the backslash(\) is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue facing was due to that i was passing arguments to function where it is considering space and not escaping it when the backslash() is added